# Fetching all Posts and Comments from a Facebook Page

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, restfb

I'm trying to fetch all the posts and comments from a Facebook Page.
This works quite good so far using the following FQL:

```
{'all_posts':
'SELECT created_time, post_id, actor_id, message, description, comments FROM stream 
   WHERE source_id=PAGE_ID ORDER BY created_time', 
'comments':
   'SELECT id, fromid, post_fbid, text, time, post_id FROM comment WHERE post_id   
    IN (SELECT post_id FROM #all_posts) ORDER BY post_id'
}
```

I'm trying to use the RestFB Library, but I get

```
com.restfb.exception.FacebookResponseStatusException: Received Facebook error response 
(code 601): Parser error: unexpected '{' at position 0.
```

when I try to execute the query:

```
List<JsonObject> queryResults = facebookClient.executeQuery(query, JsonObject.class);
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your query that you are passing to `executeQuery()`?

Comment: I passed the query mentioned after "the following fql" above to execute Query. And that was the mistake, because , as I found out now, I have to use the Multiquery-Support. I'll post the working code as answer right away.

Comment: I'll answer it later, because I have to wait 8 hours until I'm allowed to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it was a mistake on RestFB side, parsing the result json, because I got several Exceptions and was kind of confused.

The right way to do this is to use the Multiquery Support of RestFB ([Executing Multiqueries with RestFb](http://restfb.com/#executing-multiple-fql-queries))

```
Map<String, String> queries = new HashMap<String, String>();
queries.put("all_posts", "select created_time, post_id, actor_id, message, description, comments from stream where source_id=279947942083512 ORDER BY created_time");
queries.put("comments", "SELECT fromid, username, text, time, post_id FROM comment WHERE post_id in (SELECT post_id FROM #all_posts) ORDER BY post_id");

MultiqueryResults queryResults = facebookClient.executeMultiquery(queries, MultiqueryResults.class);
```

You have to provide the MultiqueryResults Bean as described in [1](http://restfb.com/#executing-multiple-fql-queries)

Comment: can someone make an example of MultiqueryResults Bean for these queries? :)

Comment: public class PostsAndCommentsMultiqueryResults {

 @Facebook("all_posts")
 private List<StreamPost> posts;
 
 @Facebook
 private List<StreamComment> comments;

 public List<StreamPost> getPosts() {
  return posts;
 }

 public List<StreamComment> getComments() {
  return comments;
 }
 
 
}

Comment: you have to create beans for StreamComment and StreamPost. You cant use the Post-Class from RestFB, because it is for the Graph API

Comment: oh, thank you very much! i was trying graph api with RestFB to do the same work but it doesn't work very well... if you know something can you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117398/restfb-doesnt-give-comments-of-post pls? :)