# RestFB doesn't give comments of post

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, restfb

i'm using [restfb](http://restfb.com/) to fetch some posts and every comment of each posts of a facebook page in this way:

```
FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(MY_ACCESS_TOKEN);
Connection<Post> pagePosts = facebookClient.fetchConnection("iPhone.page/feed", Post.class);
for (List<Post> posts : pagePosts)
    for (Post post : posts){
        for(Comment comment: post.getComments().getData()){
        //get number of likes of comment
        }
        String message = post.getMessage();
        String id      = post.getId();
        long timestamp = post.getCreatedTime().getTime()/1000;
        //store info            
    }
```

My problem borns when it fetch a post like [this](https://www.facebook.com/130489060322069/posts/422930041125702).

It has 140 comments but the `toString()` method gives me:

```
Post[actions=[...] application=null attribution=null caption=techblr.com comments=Comments[count=157 data=[]] createdTime=Wed Feb 27 14:41:58 CET 2013 ....]
```

the json part of comment is:

```
comments=Comments[count=157 data=[]]

count=157
```

but if you go on that post NOW it says 145... and there is no `data`!

What could be the problem about that? why it give me different data from real one?

Comment: i would like to access to the public facebook pages, do i have to Access_token code? because for me, my access token code seems expired time by time, so i have to create a new access toekn code once the first one expired to run the program, have you experienced this before ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved in this way:

```
private static List<FBComment> getCommentFromPost(FacebookClient client, String post_id){
    List<String> comments = new ArrayList<FBComment>();

    Connection<Comment> allComments = client.fetchConnection(post_id+"/comments", Comment.class);
    for(List<Comment> postcomments : allComments){
        for (Comment comment : postcomments){
        long likes     = comment.getLikeCount()==null?(comment.getLikes()==null?0:comment.getLikes()):comment.getLikeCount();
        comments.add(comment.getMessage()+" - "+likes);
        }
    }


    return comments;
}
```